# Mongoid query nested embed document through belongs to and embeds many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

Given the following documents, I'm trying to find a log document given a token ID.

```rb
class Log
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :tokens
end

class Token
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

I tried `Log.where('user.tokens._id': BSON::ObjectId('123ABC')` with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give some samples of your collections?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can't navigate to `user` from `log` in Mongoid Criteria because they are different collections in database (dot notation is only available when using embedding). For this case you can use aggregation pipeline:

```rb
Log.collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$lookup' => {
      from: User.collection.name,
      localField: 'user_id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'users'
    }
  },
  {
    '$match' => {
      'users.tokens' => {
        '$elemMatch' => {
          _id: { '$eq' => BSON::ObjectId('123ABC') }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).map { |doc| Log.instantiate(doc) }
```

Lookup works like join in SQL [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

`aggregate` in Mongoid returns collection of `BSON::Document`s so we use `Log.instantiate` to create `Log` instances from them.

Comment: The code looks pretty good, but it takes too much time to finish and it returns `nil`.